# SQL server - Calculate delta per duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, timespan

**Question:**

How can I calculate with only the first values for every duration (small interval) in a interval?

**Details:**

I have (many) counters (counterId column).
each counter is sampled from time to time and the sample is stored in "counter_samples" table:

*counter_samples table*:

```
id |counterId  | value  | Time                |
1  | 1         | 100    | 2015-06-12 14:00:04 |
2  | 2         | 57     | 2015-06-12 14:00:11 |
3  | 1         | 100    | 2015-06-12 15:00:43 |
4  | 2         | 59     | 2015-06-12 15:00:24 |
5  | 1         | 104    | 2015-06-12 16:00:12 |
6  | 2         | 63     | 2015-06-12 16:00:14 |
7  | 1         | 110    | 2015-06-12 17:00:25 |
8  | 2         | 70     | 2015-06-12 17:00:28 |
9  | 1         | 120    | 2015-06-12 18:00:17 |
10 | 2         | 80     | 2015-06-12 18:00:36 |
11 | 1         | 130    | 2015-06-12 19:00:04 |
12 | 2         | 90     | 2015-06-12 19:00:13 |
13 | 1         | 170    | 2015-06-12 20:00:52 |
14 | 2         | 95     | 2015-06-12 20:00:13 |
15 | 1         | 190    | 2015-06-12 21:00:11 |
16 | 2         | 99     | 2015-06-12 21:00:04 |
```

As you can see, as the time pass every counter value always bigger or equal to the value before (equal=no counting in the timespan)

What I want is for any given *interval* (@start_date AND @end_date) to query the samples table about *duration* (hour/day/week/month etc..) and get the total counting for every *duration* in the *interval*.

In example, if the interval is: 1/1/2014 - 1/1/2015 and the duration is month the result set will be 12 rows that represent the 12 month in the interval and month value for month 'i' will be **month[i+1].value - month[i].value**.

To calculate the counting I want to substract the first record of the next duration from the first record of the current duration - for the example above, if the duration is 2 hours what i want to get is (for counterId=1):

```
 |CounterId  | count  | Time                |
 | 1         | 4      | 2015-06-12 14:00:00 |
 | 1         | 16     | 2015-06-12 16:00:00 |
 | 1         | 50     | 2015-06-12 18:00:00 |
```

And for counterId=2:

```
|CounterId  | count  | Time                |
| 2         | 6      | 2015-06-12 14:00:00 |
| 2         | 17     | 2015-06-12 16:00:00 |
| 2         | 15     | 2015-06-12 18:00:00 |
```

(notice in the two queries above the time 20:00:00 is ignored becaus the is no record for 22:00:00 and above)

The time must be changed to match the **(intervalStart + duration * k)** format because I want to be able to groupBy and sum counters By time in a different query so for the above example to get:

```
| count  | Time                |
| 10     | 2015-06-12 14:00:00 |
| 33     | 2015-06-12 16:00:00 |
| 65     | 2015-06-12 18:00:00 |
```

I've been searching here & there for a good example for this issue but didnt solved it with what I found:
[Sql to select row from each day of a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492297/sql-to-select-row-from-each-day-of-a-month)

[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

[When should I use Cross Apply over Inner Join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was long time ago. anyways, I solved it in sort of ugly way. I created a separate table for every relevant duration (day/weed/month etc) and the duration table holds FK to to the first report of every interval raw data - this way I can query for knowen intervals and pull the raw values for it.